# ¿A que se debe el problema al ejecutar Apache Server en el panel de XAMPP?

Tags: windows, xampp

Recién instale Windows 7. y XAMPP.

[image: Error al ejecutar Servidor Apache de XAMPP]

[image: Estos son los paquetes que tengo instalados actualmente referentes]

Answer (score 2):

Este problema esta bastante preguntado y solventado, pero en la version de stack en ingles, te pongo aca la traduccion por si a caso.

Antes de instalar VC++ verifica las actualizaciones en tu equipo de la siguiente manera.

1. Ve a inicio - Control Panel - Windows Update
2. Verificar actualizaciones.
3. Instalar todas las actualizaciones disponibles.
4. Reinicia el sistema.

Si ya lo hiciste, ahora sigue estos pasos.

Descarga Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (64-bit)

Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 (32-bit)

(Reinstalar si ya esta instalado) luego reinicia tu equipo o usa windows updates para descarga automatica.

Link de descarga https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48145.

Creditos:

Usuario Vilthering de stackoverflow version inglés.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740438/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-whi